# Java containers- adding objects more efficiently and how to return using Identifier

Tags: java, list, arraylist, containers

Code attached in the end.

So this is my first try at java generic containers. I need to collect the objects in class Product.Java which is a random class. It has several other classes that extends product class. I have added them to a container called product using ArrayList but i doubt its efficient. Also i do not know how to call cheese instance. Is there a way i can assign an identifier to all the instances ?

```
import java.util.*;

public class GenericOrder {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Product> product = new ArrayList<Product>();
    product.add(new Fruit(123));
    product.add(new ComputerPart(65));
    product.add(new Cheese(123));
    product.add(new Service(65));
    product.add(new Peripheral  (123));

    System.out.println(product);
  }
}
```

Comment: I can't understand anything to your question. Why would that be "not efficient"? How do you come to this conclusion?

Comment: @JBNizet
Im sorry for not being clear, english is my 3rd language. :)
I Believe its not efficient since i have seen examples in book where i could just add all the instances of the said objects from Product.java by just saying product.add(new fruit(),new Cheese ,...)
Where as i have to do it on Separate calls.

Comment: Read the javadoc of List. No, there is no such method.

Comment: So that means i will infact have to add them one by one. 
Is there a way i can add an identifier to each of these ?

Comment: You could use Arrays.asList and List.addAll to make it a single add, but it would not be more efficient.

Comment: @DonRoby 
Would i be able to add an identifier to each instance then aswell ? ?

Comment: @ArsalanKhan if you want identifier for each of instance you may use `HashMap<Key,Value>` to store object.

Comment: I don't know what you mean with "identifier" but a `List` in Java is really just a list of items, the only extra information "stored" by a list is the index/position of an item. You can wrap your current items in a container which consists of some identifier along with your old items and make a list thereof if you like. In case you try to access items based on some identifier, have a look at [`Map`s](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html). http://java67.blogspot.de/2013/01/difference-between-set-list-and-map-in-java.html explains the differences and intentions quite well.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating @zapl

Comment: Maybe what you're looking for is http://idlebrains.org/tutorials/java-tutorials/effective-java-typesafe-heterogeneous-container-pattern/ | https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#ClassToInstanceMap